# Search a pattern and replace the entire line of a perl module file

Tags: regex, perl

I have a perl module file. like this :

```
$release_name       = 'Software Release';
$primary_version    = '1';
$secondary_version  = 'R00.0';
$Main_version   = 'R00.0';
```

I want to search the Main_version and replace the line to

```
      $Main_version = R00.1
```

when i run the script.
I have tried like this. but its not working.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use strict;
my $base;
my $file = "/main-dir/work/Myfile.pm";
open(FILE, $file) || die "File not found";
my @base = <FILE>;
close(FILE);
my $item = '$Main_version';
my newitem="R00.1";
foreach $base(@base)
    {
      if($base =~ /$item/){
         $base =~ s/$item/$item='$newitem'/gi;
         print ("Hello, world!\n");
      }
    #else { print $base;}
}
open (BASE, ">$file");
print BASE @base;
close (BASE);
```

How to search and change the entire line of a perl module? Thanks.

Comment: Rewriting Perl code is difficult and prone to errors and security problems.  Have you considered using a configuration file like [JSON](https://metacpan.org/pod/JSON::MaybeXS) or [YAML](https://metacpan.org/pod/YAML)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had you used the standard VERSION variable, you could have profited from [perl-reversion](https://metacpan.org/pod/release/BDFOY/Perl-Version-1.013/examples/perl-reversion).

The dollar sign is special in regular expressions, it means "the end of the line". Backslash it, or use [quotemeta](http://p3rl.org/quotemeta) which could be shortened to `\Q` in a regex:

```
$base =~ /\Q$item/
```

Comment: hi, thanks. But it replaces string with many extra "\". any solution? @choroba

Comment: @no1: `s/\Q$item/$item='$newitem'/`. No `\Q` in the replacement.

Comment: thanks. i get $Main_version = R00.1   R00.0; i want to remove R00.0 from the line?

Comment: @no1: You want to replace more than just `$item`.

Comment: yeah. find item and replace the next.

Comment: @no1: So match the rest of the line, too: `$base =~ s/\Q$item\E.*/$item='$newitem'/gi;`